# Retrieve IAuthRepository from ServiceStackController

Tags: servicestack

I've upgraded an old ASP.Net Mvc project that uses Servicestack from 4.0.40 to 4.5 but I've seen that when calling the base.HasRole I've to pass an IAuthRepository, I was wondering if there's a way to get it from ServiceStackController or in the IAuthSession

Consider the following snippet

```
   protected override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ViewBag.UICulture = this.UICulture ?? "it-IT";
        ViewBag.MiniProfiler = AppSettings.Get<bool>(Resources.MiniProfilerKey, false);

        if (UserSession.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            ViewBag.IsAdmin = this.UserSession?.HasRole(RoleNames.Admin) ?? false;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.UserAuthName))
            {
                ViewBag.UserName = this.UserAuthName;
            }

            var userSession = UserSession as IFMSAuthUserSession;

            if (userSession != null)
            {
                userSession.UserImpersonated = GetImpersonatedUser(Module);

                var menu = userSession.Menu?.Clone();

                if (menu == null)
                {
                    int t = 0;
                }

                ViewData[Resources.ModulesData] = userSession.GetAuthorizedModules().Skip(1); //salta home
                ViewData[Resources.MenuData] = menu;
                ViewData[Resources.BreadCrumbData] = menu?.LightMenu(Regex.Replace(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, "/$", ""));
            }
        }
    }
```

That's defined inside an abstract class

```
  public abstract class BaseController<T> : ModuleController<T>
    where T : class, ServiceStack.Auth.IAuthSession
```

where ModuleController is

```
  public abstract class ModuleController : ModuleController<MyAuthUserSession>
{ }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from the `ServiceStackController`, e.g:

```
var ssController = filterContext.Controller as ServiceStackController;
var authRepo = ssController?.AuthRepository;
```

Otherwise outside of ServiceStack you can get it directly from `AppHost.GetAuthRepository()` singleton but you'll need access to the `IRequest` (e.g. available from `ServiceStackRequest` in `ServiceStackController`):

```
var authProvider = HostContext.AppHost.GetAuthRepository(req);
```